# Convert model to array mvc 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I got a model what i want is by clicking on a button to run a javascript function which will convert that model into array and send it to a controller that will read and parse the data as json or just as a Model.

example:

[View]:

```
@model MyApp.MyModel

<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="SendData()" />

function SendData()
{
   var data = "@Model" // this is where im stuck maybe $.makeArray("@Model") ?
   $.ajax({
            url: 'getData',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $.toJSON(data),
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Json.Encode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) could help you

> Converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

And your code

```
var data = @Json.Encode(Model);
```

Comment: will it work on the model if its IEnumerable ?? because Encode takes an object not as a list or am i wrong? exp: @model IEnumerable<MyApp.MyClass>

Comment: Any class in c# is derived from object. So it should work on IEnumerable too. Why wouldn't you try and see it yourself? :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to the answer by @archil.

It may be better to use **@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))**, depending on your requirements, instead of just **Json.Encode(Model)** because the json object will be properly encoded.

Example Json data using *@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))*

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Joe"}]
```

Example Json data using *Json.Encode(Model)*

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Joe&quot;}]
```